# list.reverse() doesn't work properly in Django

Tags: python, django, pagination, blogs

I am on my first project with the Django framework, and I decided to create a blog, since it is easy to find stuff about it online. I, then, found out about the Paginator module, and decided to use it. The problem is, whenever I add a post it goes to the end of the Database, so I have a blog that, so far, displays old posts first.

Because of that, I decided to use .reverse(), like this:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    posts.reverse()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 2)

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get("page", "1"))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('index.html', {
                                             'Posts': posts,
                                             'Sideposts': Sidepost.objects.all(),
                                             })
```

The only problem is, this doesn't work, at least not with Paginator. When I stop using Paginator it works, but otherwise it doesn't.

I think this is a really weird behaviour, and I had a look around but couldn't find anything that helped me with this problem. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the database do the ordering:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

Of course, it would be better to use a date field or something.

Comment: This is better because it will allow the pagination to only load what you need for the page. Casting to a list loads everything in the query.

Answer (score 2):

First, `Post.objects.all()` does not return a list object, but queryset object.

And [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.reverse) method does not change the queryset itself, but returns reversed version of queryset.

Convert it to list `posts = list(Post.objects.all())` to use `reverse` method if you want list object.

Maybe following is more preferable:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().reverse()
```

Comment: If it didnt have `reverse` method, wouldnt the problem have failed to execute?

Comment: It worked, thanks! As for the second part, since I want to sort my posts by time, and every time I add a new one it goes to the end of the Database, shouldn't just `.reverse()` be enough for my purposes?

Comment: @AugustoQ, I updated the answer. My initial answer about `reverse` method was wrong. `Queryset.reverse` returns new queryset instead of changing the queryset itself unlike `list.reverse`.

Comment: @falsetru, your first answer actually worked. This one now I had tried before and it didn't. - When I put `posts = Post.objects.all().reverse()` nothing happens, just like when I put them separately. When I use `posts = list(Post.objects.all())` and then `posts.reverse()`, it works perfectly.

Comment: @AugustoQ, Did you try `order_by('...')` ?